# unique_ptr versus heap allocating and delete

Tags: c++, pointers, new-operator, unique-ptr, delete-operator

Say that I have a class `A` and a class `B` which further has a subclass `B1`.  Now I want to assign a pointer of `B1` to be a member of `A`.  I could do that by simply heap allocating `B1` and then using `delete` in the destructor of `A` as follows:

```
class B {
    public:
        B() { };
};

class B1 : public B {
    public:
        B1() { };
};


class A {
    public:
         B* b_instance;

         A(B* b_instance){
             this->b_instance = b_instance;
         };

         ~A(){
             delete this->b_instance;
         };
};

int main() {
    B* b_instance = new B1();
    A a_instance(b_instance);
    return 0;
};
```

Now I believe another approach (and one that is more favored?) would use `std::unique_ptr`, whereby a `unique_ptr` to `B1` is given to `A` and thus, as a smart pointer, whenever `A` is destroyed `B1` is automatically destroyed as well since there are no more references to it.  My best guess is that it should look something like this:

```
#include <memory>

class B {
    public:
        B() { };
};

class B1 : public B {
    public:
        B1() { };
};


class A {
    public:
         std::unique_ptr<B> b_instance;

         A(B& b_instance){
             this->b_instance = std::make_unique<B>(b_instance);
         };

         ~A(){ };
};

int main() {
    B1 b_instance;
    A a_instance(b_instance);
    return 0;
};
```

Is the `unique_ptr` approach the same as the approach outlined above so long as you remember to include `delete this->b_instance` in the destructor of `A`?  Or are there other benefits of the `unique_ptr` approach?

Comment: (1) If the constructor of `A` throws, then the d'tor will never be called and the resource could leak. (2) The default copy assignment c'tor of A is implicitly defined in your example, so you can do `A new = a_instance;` and end up double-freeing your resource. (3) If you have a unique_ptr defined then the default copy c'tor won't be created (unique_ptr can only be moved).

Comment: Note there are 5 methods in a class that can automatically be generated by the compiler (see rule of 3/5). If you are not careful in your original version the compiler generated methods could result in multiple `A` objects containing the same pointer, resulting in multiple deletes on the pointer. The use of `unique_ptr` will prevent this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is the `unique_ptr` approach the same as the approach outlined above so long as you remember to include `delete this->b_instance` in the destructor of `A`?

More or less.

> Or are there other benefits of the `unique_ptr` approach?

Yes, you get automatic move semantics and copy semantics is turned off, greatly helping to prevent involuntary multiple owners of the same resource.